# autolayout set view to screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have read tutorials about the auto layout but i just couldn't understand the basic things, where they all deals with technical ways to handle Xcode, i couldn't find a simple, clear , explanation to it .

So I will ask 2 basic questions, for 1 problem, a simple problem.

Problem: I have created `UIImageView` in `storyboard`, inside a view controller .
I would like this view, to **always be in the screen size, no matter what iPhone it is** .

1. One way i was thinking about, is just to set it with code, to be in the screen size, this does not works, and in simulator(Xcode 6 - iPhone 6) i see its cover part of the screen.

> ```
> float width= [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
> float height=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
>  self.backImage.frame=CGRectMake( 0,
>                                   0
>                                      , width, height) ;
> ```

Why is this not working(because the image view is checked for auto layout ? )

2. How to define layouts  in `storyboard`, for this view, to always cover the screen size exactly ?
3. What if after i set constrains, i would like to set some effect for this view- to move, in code, for example setting the image view size to be 1.5 screen size and centered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove any other constraints that define the width or the height of the `UIImageView`. Open the Pin Tool constraints tab (Interface builder, at the bottom right, third button from the left), and set all the `Spacing to nearest neighbour` constraints to 0. Now click Apply Constraints, and update your frame.

Comment: Thats what i did thanks, but somehow when you run the iPhone 6 simulator, the image is still not covering the screen but i have this left side uncovered, even that i set constrains to be 0 for all sides .

Comment: I dont have an option to set "to nearest neighbour" , i just see that sentence in there,but the options are bottom layout and view(current=0), and these did not helped.

Comment: I'll update my answer as soon as I home. I'll test it myself.

Comment: i set it to 0 as you said, but than the "add constrains" button is disabled(its grey) .